# Is it possible to use the Rōv scanner that ships with Delicious Library for general purpose scanning?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, scanning

I have the package of a [Microvision Rōv bluetooth barcode scanner](http://www.microvision.com/store/product.php?productid=2) and the [Delicious Library](http://www.delicious-monster.com/) software and it works awesomely well to scan UPC of books, dvd, and gadgets of all sorts into the library.

What I'd like to do is scan some other data using this hardware and don't know how to get at the data that the barcode scanner captures but that Delicious Library is bypassing (serial number, IMEI, etc...). I have asked both companies for assistance with this, but wondered if anyone here had an answer before I get the "official responses". I will answer / comment as I get responses from the companies.

Does anyone have recommendations for software to scan arbitrary bar code data into a spreadsheet or structured text file so I can parse these other fields and use this scanner for data entry past what the Delicious Library software allows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bmike

From memory, Delicious Library includes the software component required to communicate with serial io devices such as USB and Bluetooth scanners like the Microvision ROV

Thee may be other ways to interface but the recommended solution from the scanner manufacturer is a piece of software, SerialMagic or SerialMagic Pro from a company called Serial IO

http://serialio.com/products/SerialMagic/index.php

Currently retailing at 50 USD

Comment: Thank you so much. SerialIO was crashing on me and I have an open ticket and beta build to test - it looks promising for what I ask. Delicious monster also provided a beta build that logs verbose scamming data to re system logs so I will scrape the data from there for my current project.

Answer (score 0):

Although serial magic is the correct answer - I also have great luck from Delicious Library support. They pointed out that their beta builds log barcode data to the console and I was able to scrape the log file for the data I needed without resorting to the work and cost of getting Serial Magic running.

Comment: Well yeah I love DM; Wil, Jonathan & Lia (and the ex-Monsters like Terry) are/were a pretty helpful bunch.  That Stu Wilson guy over there helps a lot too :p

Comment: Do you actually work for DM?

Comment: Am I an employee? No, just a power user with moderator permissions